# Unable to add Both Individual and Company Params to AccountParams

Tags: android, stripe-payments

According to the latest update from Stripe, to verify information with the IRS, the legal name and tax ID are required. However, when using the Stripe Android SDK, it's currently not possible to include both company parameters and individual parameters in a single AccountParams object.

The create function in AccountParams accepts either individual or company parameters. There are no errors during token creation, and the test logs indicate successful requests. However, the callback returns a pending status with the name and tax ID pending, as they are not included in the token, leading to a pending status in connected account creation.
The following structure is required for creating an account token

```
{
  "account": {
    "tos_shown_and_accepted": "true",
    "individual": {
      "dob": {
        "year": "****",
        "day": "*",
        "month": "**"
      },
      "id_number": "*********",
      "ssn_last_4": "****",
      "phone": "*****",
      "first_name": "ABC",
      "address": {
        "line1": "test",
        "state": "Alabama",
        "postal_code": "08540",
        "city": "test",
        "country": "US"
      },
      "email": "abc@newagesmb.com",
      "last_name": "D"
    },
    "company": {
      "tax_id": "***********",
      "name": "ABC"
    },
    "business_type": "individual"
  },
}
```

Comment: You would want to take the errored request id from https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs first and confirm what it sent. Btw why are you calling Account API, which is a backend API, via Android?

Comment: I'm not making any API calls from the frontend. I couldn't find a method for creating a token using AccountParams that accepts both individual and company parameters. There are no errors during token creation, and the test logs indicate successful requests. However, the callback returns a pending status with the name and tax ID pending, as they are not included in the token, leading to a pending status in connected account creation.